# String Contains Does Not Work In LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I've always used **Contains** method to gain SQL IN functionality to my LINQ queries.

But this time, very strange thing occured.

I've got an array of string like this :

```
string[] FilenamesToParse = {"JOHN_X200-", "DOE_X300-", "FOO_X300_M-"};
```

Then I've used this array just like below:

```
var result = (from dps in appProcessList
                   where FilenamesToParse.Contains(dps.FileName)
                   select dps.Devices).ToList()
```

Above query resulted with 0 result but I'm sure that there are filenames contains words defined in `FilenamesToParse`  array.

So I've tried below snippet and **Contains** worked.

```
foreach (var applicationProcess in appProcessList)
{
   if (applicationProcess.FileName.Contains(FilenamesToParse[0]))
   {

   }
}
```

Where am I wrong here ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I'm sure that there are filenames contains words defined in FilenamesToParse array.* I am sure it is not, but how would we test without knowing what is in the array?

Comment: What are some values for dps.FileName.  It would help to know what data is being checked...

Comment: The second check is the other way around from the first one...

Comment: `where FilenamesToParse.Contains(dps.FileName)` dps.FileName would have to be an **exact match** of one of the strings in the array, wouldn't it?

Comment: Your two appraoches aren´t similar. In your linq you´re iterating your `FilenamesToParse`-array and check if any of its elements *exactly matches* `dps.FileName`, whereby in the second one you iterate `appProcessList` and check if its `FileName`-property *contains* the first `FilenamesToParse`.

Comment: [`Array.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015.aspx), which is essentially what you're calling in the first example, is different from [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx), which is what you're calling in the second example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two appraoches aren´t similar. In your linq you´re iterating your `FilenamesToParse`-array and check if any of its elements *exactly matches* `dps.FileName`, whereby in the second one you iterate `appProcessList` and check if its `FileName`-property *contains* the first `FilenamesToParse`.

The following would be the linq-approach similar to your loop:

```
var result = (from dps in appProcessList
               where FilenamesToParse.Any(x => dps.FileName.Contains(x))
               select dps.Devices).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for that approach ! I've realized it after a quick look at definition of Contains in LINQ. I've accomplished it by adding extra foreach after query but this is far more clear approach.

Comment: deferred execution (=>) is the key, this is a great way to explain same